# ¿Cómo puedo arreglar este error en virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

estoy trabajando con Python 3.6.4 e instalé Django 1.8 en mi proyecto creado con virtualenv (obviamente antes había instalado el virtualenv). El problema es que ahora dentro de la carpeta que me creó el virtualenv quiero crear un proyecto con el comando `django-admin.py startproject mysite .` sin embargo me lanza un error que dice:
`traceback (most recent call last)`

```
File "C:\Users\Ignacio\Desktop\mientorno\Scripts\django-admin.py", line2, in <module> from django.core import management
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'django'
```

La verdad es que esto me parece raro porque según lo que entiendo me dice que no existe un archivo llamada django-admin.py en ese directorio. Pero si existe y además el django 1.8 fue instalado exitosamente. ¿El problema son las versiones?

Agradecería mucho su ayuda. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Entonces parece que efectivamente tienes django bien instalado en el entorno. Podemos borrar todos los comentarios previos para dejar más limpia la pregunta. Por desgracia no puedo seguir con esto hasta dentro de 10h. A ver si alguien da antes con tu problema. Yo sospecho que pueda estar en que hayas intentado crear el proyecto django dentro de la misma carpeta que creaste con virtualenv

Comment: Si, eso estaba haciendo, ¿debe hacerse de otra manera?

Comment: En principio una cosa es la carpeta creada por virtualenv, que contiene una instalación de python,independiente de la del sistema, más los paquetes que allí instales, y otra diferente la carpeta en la que vayas a desarrollar algo haciendo uso de esos paquetes. Lo normal es tenerlo separado. Si además, como consecuencia de lo que estás desarrollando, creas una carpeta llamada django o jn script django.py, eso puede interferir con los import.

Comment: También puede deberse a que la primera linea de manage.py declare un ejecutable python distinto del instalado por virtualenv, como se describe aqui https://stackoverflow.com/a/10756446/1264820

Comment: Ah ok. Muchas gracias. Veré si puedo solucionarlo.

Comment: @Pandehuevo, tal vez este de más preguntarlo, pero has iniciado el entorno? es decir corriendo el `activate.bat`

Comment: Primero, no es recomendable crear el proyecto dentro de la misma carpeta del entorno, segundo, podrias describir que comando utilizaste para instalar django ?

Comment: Hola, disculpen por la demora, respondiendo a la indicación de @PatricioMoracho, todavía no he hecho lo que tú dijiste, yo activo el entorno virtual con el comando `mientono\Scripts\activate` (esto lo hago cuando me ubico en el escritorio con la consola de windows) \n Respecto a lo que señaló @jsanchezs, podrías indicarme cómo crear el proyecto en otra carpeta? Django lo instalé usando el comando `pip install django==1.8`

Answer (score -1):

No puedo seguir todo el hilo, parece que se borraron respuestas. Podrías poner toda la secuencia de comandos que hiciste para crear el entorno virtual e instalar Django.
Otra cosa que puedes chequear también, con el entorno activado, es `pip list` para listar los paquetes instalados y ver si tiene `Django 1.8.x` ahí dentro. Luego puedes hacer `pip show Django` para que te muestre la información de ese paquete. Entre ellas te va a mostrar info de donde está alojado en el item "Location"

Comment: tienes un comentario y una respuesta en el campo de respuesta, por favor separa una cosa de otra para darle una solución mas clara, por favor lee [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: No entiendo lo que me queres decir. Le estoy dando una respuesta. No recuerdo haber escrito un comentario y respuesta.